# How to made good table in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to have a table just like this. How can I do that? I want just like this expect of green and light green color. I want use purple and orchid

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example without Bootstrap. I used font-awesome for icon, look the complete code here https://codepen.io/alex-grz/pen/KKNZvOZ.

```css
table {
   font-family: sans-serif;
}
.table>tbody>tr>td, 
.table>tbody>tr>th, 
.table>tfoot>tr>td, 
.table>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table>thead>tr>td, 
.table>thead>tr>th {
  text-align:center;
   padding:1rem 3rem;
   font-size: .8rem;
}

.table > thead > tr > th:first-child {
  background-color:unset;
}

.table > thead > tr > th {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; 
}

.table > tbody > tr > th { 
  border-radius: 6px 0 0px 6px;
}

.table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > th  {
  background-color:#9BD727;
  color:white; 
}

.table > tbody > tr > td {
   background-color:#DEF2CC;
  color:black;
}

.table>tfoot>tr>td {
  color: #9BD727;
  font-size:1rem;
}

.fa-check {
  color:#9BD727;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  
<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">Smart Starter</th>
        <th scope="col">Smart Medium</th>
        <th scope="col">Smart Buisiness</th>
        <th scope="col">Smart Deluxe</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Storage Space</th>
        <td>512 MB</td>
        <td>1 GB</td>
        <td>2 GB</td>
        <td>4 GB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Bandiwdth</th>
        <td>50 GB</td>
        <td>100 GB</td>
        <td>150 GB</td>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">MySQL Databases</th>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Setup</th>
        <td>19.90 $</td>
        <td>12.90 $</td>
        <td>free</td>
        <td>free</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">PHP 5</th>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Ruby on Rails</th>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Price per month</th>
          <td>$ 2.90</td>
          <td>$ 5.90</td>
          <td>$ 9.90</td>
          <td>$ 14.90</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh thats awesome!thank you so much and god bless you!

Comment: This is very good. However, since there is no statement of the actual problem in the question, the question may well be put on hold. It is worth noting that not all problems are on-topic here, and if you want your work to survive, it is best to answer questions where an obvious effort has been expended.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize bootstrap tables to make clean tables in HTML.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

Also an alternative => Material UI

https://material-ui.com/

If using react, use react strap

https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tables/

Comment: sorry bro.i couldnt find it.can you make it for me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place to gather knowledge and learn deeper into coding. If you want, feel free to contact me and I can accomplish your project for a payment. Other than that, I don't believe you will find someone here to accomplish free labor

Comment: no problem with payment. just gimme price and eth addres!

Comment: ref my website on my account for contact info

Answer (score 0):

Just for check marks i made use of external plugin. You can remove it. Remove "stylesheet in head tag"  AND  replace i tag"<_i class = 'fa_fa_check '><  /i>" in table cell with    '&#x2713';

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
table{
width:60%;
margin:auto;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
}
table tr td, table th{
padding:10px 10px;
text-align:center;
background:#da70d6;
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-top-color: transparent;
border-right-color: transparent;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
border-left-color: transparent;
font-size: 1rem;
line-height: 1.5;
border-radius: .25rem;
transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
table th{
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6441A5 0%, #2a0845  51%, #6441A5  100%);
color:#fff;
text-shadow:1px 1px #000;
font-weight:800;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) th:nth-child(1){
background:none;
}
table tr:nth-child(15) td, table tr:nth-child(15) th{
background:none;
color:#6441A5;
font-size:1.5em;
text-shadow:1px 1px #000;
}
table td i{
color:#6441A5;
}

@media (max-width:900px){
table{
max-width:99%;
width:99%;
}
table tr td, table th{
font-size:0.7em;
}
table tr:nth-child(15) td, table tr:nth-child(15) th{
font-size:1em;
}
}

@media (max-width:450px){
table{
max-width:99%;
width:99%;
}
table tr td, table th{
font-size:0.6em;
}
table tr:nth-child(15) td, table tr:nth-child(15) th{
font-size:0.7em;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Smart Starter</th>
<th>Smart Medium</th>
<th>Smart Business</th>
<th>Smart Deluxe</th>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Storage Space</th>
<td>512MB</td>
<td>1GB</td>
<td>2GB</td>
<td>4GB</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Band Width</th>
<td>50GB</td>
<td>100GB</td>
<td>150GB</td>
<td>Unlimited</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>MySQL Databases</th>
<td>Unlimited</td>
<td>Unlimited</td>
<td>Unlimited</td>
<td>Unlimited</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Setup</th>
<td>19.90 $</td>
<td>12.90 $</td>
<td>free</td>
<td>free</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>PHP 5</th>
<td>&#x2713;</td>
<td>&#x2713;</td>
<td>&#x2713;</td>
<td>&#x2713;</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Ruby On Rails</th>
<td>&#x2713;</td>
<td>&#x2713;</td>
<td>&#x2713;</td>
<td>&#x2713;</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Price per month</th>
<td>$ 2.90</td>
<td>$ 5.90</td>
<td>$ 9.90</td>
<td>$ 14.90</td>
<tr>
</table>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
table{
width:60%;
margin:auto;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
}
table tr td, table th{
padding:10px 10px;
text-align:center;
background:#da70d6;
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-top-color: transparent;
border-right-color: transparent;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
border-left-color: transparent;
font-size: 1rem;
line-height: 1.5;
border-radius: .25rem;
transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
table th{
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6441A5 0%, #2a0845  51%, #6441A5  100%);
color:#fff;
text-shadow:1px 1px #000;
font-weight:800;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) th:nth-child(1){
background:none;
}
table tr:nth-child(15) td, table tr:nth-child(15) th{
background:none;
color:#6441A5;
font-size:1.5em;
text-shadow:1px 1px #000;
}
table td i{
color:#6441A5;
}

@media (max-width:900px){
table{
max-width:99%;
width:99%;
}
table tr td, table th{
font-size:0.7em;
}
table tr:nth-child(15) td, table tr:nth-child(15) th{
font-size:1em;
}
}

@media (max-width:450px){
table{
max-width:99%;
width:99%;
}
table tr td, table th{
font-size:0.6em;
}
table tr:nth-child(15) td, table tr:nth-child(15) th{
font-size:0.7em;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Smart Starter</th>
<th>Smart Medium</th>
<th>Smart Business</th>
<th>Smart Deluxe</th>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Storage Space</th>
<td>512MB</td>
<td>1GB</td>
<td>2GB</td>
<td>4GB</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Band Width</th>
<td>50GB</td>
<td>100GB</td>
<td>150GB</td>
<td>Unlimited</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>MySQL Databases</th>
<td>Unlimited</td>
<td>Unlimited</td>
<td>Unlimited</td>
<td>Unlimited</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Setup</th>
<td>19.90 $</td>
<td>12.90 $</td>
<td>free</td>
<td>free</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>PHP 5</th>
<td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
<td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
<td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
<td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Ruby On Rails</th>
<td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
<td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
<td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
<td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Price per month</th>
<td>$ 2.90</td>
<td>$ 5.90</td>
<td>$ 9.90</td>
<td>$ 14.90</td>
<tr>
</table>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfect table mahesh! thank you so much.is anyway to do it without bootstrap?just with html css? can you do it too?